# Rate of new tickets in tfs Dashboard

Tags: tfs

We are running visual studio team foundation server and today we are watching the number of active bugs on a dashboard. I would like to accompany this information with the number of new bugs added to the buglist each day.

I can't find any widget or anything in this area, is there anyone that have any idea how to track this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a cumulative flow chart that will show you the increase in tye number of bugs by day.

Create a query with the last 30 days of bugs by created date (@today-30). Then go to the Chart tab on the query and add a line chart. Tweek & pin it to your dasboard. Call it "30 day cumulative bug flow".

Another useful way to visualise this data would be to create a query for those bugs created in the last 24 hours, (@today-1) and pin it to your dashboard as a number. Call it "Incoming in last 24"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no this kind of build-in feature.

You could use TFS *Client API* or *REST API* to query workitems and create the status report yourself.

Or you could [set an optional reporting infrastructure.](https://nkdagility.com/integrate-reporting-and-analyses-services-with-team-foundation-server-2013/) With this installed you can use the [out of the box reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd380714.aspx) to do what you want:

Moreover, I also created an [uservoice](http://A%20way%20to%20show%20the%20number%20of%20new%20bugs%20added%20to%20the%20buglist%20each%20day%20on%20the%20dashboard.) for you, TFS Admin will kindly review it, you could also vote up it to get more attention.